# AJAX Load function from php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

;-) I have a hit a brick wall. Today I have met Ajax for the first time in my life. And I understand, that my question can seem very stupid. But I need your help.

I have a php file (for ex. index.php), it has an include (*function.php*). In the file *function.php* I have a function (for example `function Jokes(){....}`).

I want to use AJAX to load this function in my page. But I don't know how to do this... :-(

I have found some easy solutions (I use Jquery load function), but it's not what I want, because I have to use a separate file.

```
$('#jokes').load('jokes.php');
```

But I need something like:

```
$('#jokes').load('function.php','jokes()');
```

Any help or ideas? It will be appreciated.

P.S: Sorry for my bad English...))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is make one AJAX file, e.g. ajaxfunctions.php where you divide the functions.

```
$('#jokes').load("ajax.php", { 'function': 'jokes' } );
```

In your PHP file ajax.php you can do this:

```
<?php
include 'function.php';
if (isset ($_POST['function']) && $_POST['function'] == 'jokes')
{
    echo jokes ();
}
?>
```

Does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

The browser (and thus Ajax) can only make HTTP requests to the server.

It cannot execute specific functions.

You would have to write server side code that would recognise a particular URL (e.g. to a script that only calls that function, or a script that decides which function to run based on the query string) and execute a particular function in response to a request to it.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's impossible to do it this way. You must make a request to a url. You can't just invoke a specific function from a php file.

Build a url wrapper for the function you need.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that.
Ajax is used to send or retrieve data, but what you are trying to do is to load a Javascript function defined in a PHP file (isn't it?).
Instead, just define your Javascript function in a JS file and load it via a script (or, if it should be loaded dynamically, you may use an AMD loader like require.js)

If you want to load a PHP function in JS, then it's not possible. You may call that function and fetch its result instead, though.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work like this.

```
$('#jokes').load('jokes.php');
```

does an http request to jokes.php. If you want to execute a specific function, you can use a parameter, like this:

```
$('#jokes').load('jokes.php?func=jokes');
```

From your php script, get 'func' and execute the proper function.

```
...
function jokes() {
   return 'some output';
}

...
$func='';
if (!empty($_REQUEST['func'])) {
  $func=$_REQUEST['func'];
}

if ($func=='jokes') {
  echo jokes();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need AJAX for this. You want to put the Jokes() function in a JavaScript file, maybe called Jokes.js, include it in index.php and then call it normally in a JavaScript block in index.php.

Comment: `function Jokes` is almost certainly a **PHP** function, not a JavaScript function.

Comment: From the syntax, it could be a JavaScript function, though, to be fair, it is unclear.